# Django - ManyToMany - how to filter on parent's ManyToMany object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have problems with writing a filter on my queryset models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
  items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderLine)
  store = models.ForeignKey(Store, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class OrderLine(models.Model):
  orderItemId = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
  quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Store(models.Model):
  storeName = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
  access_from_account = models.ManyToManyField(EDUser, blank=True)
```

I have my queryset of EDUser "**accounts**"
Now I want to select OrderLines that belongs to Order that are from Store that is visible by an account in access_from _account.

So, for example:

**store_name_1** has **access_from_account** user_1, user_2

**store_name_2** has **access_from_account** user_1

There at **Orders** that belongs to **store_name_1**. Those Orders have many **OrderLines**.
I would like to select order_lines that should be accessible by **user_1**.

Can I do it by:
**acounts** is queryset of ['user_1']

`lines = OrderLine.objects.filter(order__store__access_from_account__in=accounts)?`
I tried that, but I get some strange values...

Any suggestion of how to do it properly? I would like to avoid making lists and iterate over them.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't need the `__in` lookup, so lines = `OrderLine.objects.filter(order__store__access_from_account=user1)` is sufficient, exactly what are the "strange values"?

Comment: so, for one of my store that I have a few lines, I got results like I had a few hundreds. But your answer solved my problem. Blessed `.distinct()` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query

```
lines = OrderLine.objects.filter(
    order__store__access_from_account__in=accounts
)
```

will work propery. The only problem is that if `accounts` contains two users, like `user1` and `user2`, and both accounts have access to a store, it will *duplicate* the lines. You will thus retrieve `OrderLine`s for `user1` and for `user2`. This is due to the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the junction table in between. You can solve this by making use of [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

```
lines = OrderLine.objects.filter(
    order__store__access_from_account__in=accounts
).distinct()
```

If you are working with a single `EDUser`, then you do not need the `__in` lookup:

```
# for a single user

lines = OrderLine.objects.filter(
    order__store__access_from_account=myuser
)
```